# Why Basic auth credentials presented in all XHR requests after login

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, nginx, fetch

I have issue with basic auth in conjunction with other API server in my network. Simple scheme:

[image]

1. Browser send GET request to Nginx server
2. Nginx responses with 401
3. User send Basic Auth credentials
4. Nginx responses with 200. Browser loads static files (CSS + JS) and evaluate them.
5. In JS there is a fetch to another API (with CORS included)
6. But I see Auth header with basic auth credentials in all requests to the API server.

Question is why? Does this a way which browser works? How I can remove them if I'm not controlling given JS file?

I'm using Nginx basic auth module with very simple config:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;

    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

Comment: You can simply remove the "Authorization" header from your request if you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Question is why? Does this a way which browser works?*

Yes, this is the way browser works, with good reason. According to [RFC2617](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt), for Basic Authentication Scheme:

> A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
>      the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
>      are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of
>      the current challenge. A client MAY **preemptively** send the
>      corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in
>      that space without receipt of another challenge from the server.

In this question's case, if `GET /` HTTP request get Basic auth response (`401 Unauthorized`, `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="..."` response header), and the authentication succeed, all following HTTP requests will have `Authorization` header automatically. This is designed to improve user experience -- otherwise, the authentication dialog will alway be popped up when new HTTP request is sent. Imagine, if 4 pages `/`, `/my-account`, `/my-orders`, `/my-address` are visited, the authentication dialog will be popped up 4 times and force user to input credential again and again, which is very painful.

*How I can remove them if I'm not controlling given JS file?*

To prevent browser from sending `Authorization` header for some pages, there are 2 methods:

1. Configure Nginx and only enable Basic auth on some URLs, such as `/secure/...`. In this way, HTTP requests to non-secure URL won't have `Authorization` header.
2. Use Digest auth and configure `domain` attribute in `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Answer (score 0):

You can right a function which will return all the necessary headers according to the request type. Suppose you want some API to be public, then you can conditionally set the headers.

```
const getToken = () => ({
 "Authorization": `Token ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
})

function getHeaders(type) {
  const json_headers = {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  if(type === "Public"){
    return return Object.assign({}, json_headers)
  } else {
     return Object.assign({}, json_headers, getToken())
  }
}
```

And then you can pass these header to your ajax/fetch API.

```
let fetchOptions = {
  method,
  headers: getHeaders(type),
}

fetch(url, fetchOptions)
```

Comment: But in my JS i'm clearly passing headers to fetch without Auth header, but it is anyway present in request.